# Installed Ruby 1.9.2 but new gems won't create scripts into /usr/bin

Tags: 10.10, ruby, rvm

I had previously ruby 1.8 on my Ubuntu 10.10, which I removed through Synaptics. Then I have installed ruby 1.9.1 also via Synaptics (which is then saying that itself is version 1.9.2).
Then I installed ruby-debug19 and rspec gems with `sudo gem install ruby-debug19 rspec`

However I can't start `rdebug` or `rspec`, but I can invoke the debugger from inside my ruby script, so the debugger is working. 
I inspected the starting scripts `rdebug` and `rspec` and then I realized that they are still old scripts back from ruby1.8 time. In other words, the current 1.9 install of these gems haven't created the starting scripts anywhere.

What is the easiest solution for a lazy soul like me? It looks like removing-reinstalling ruby 1.9.2 won't help, and installing these gems over and over again won't create the starting scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, Rubygems on Ubuntu and Debian use /var/lib/gems/$ruby_version as their installation root (to keep gems installed via apt, and manually-installed gems cleanly separated).

In your case, since you're using Ruby 1.9, the executables should be installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9/bin. Try adding something like this into your ~/.bashrc file:

```
export PATH="/var/lib/gems/1.9/bin:$PATH"
```