# How do I start a ruby/gem program?

Tags: 11.10, ruby, gem

I have installed [taskjuggler](http://rubygems.org/gems/taskjuggler) (`gem install taskjuggler`), but now I have no idea how to start it...

```
$ taskjuggler
taskjuggler: command not found

$ gem taskjuggler
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    Unknown command taskjuggler
```

this one was on the taskjuggler page, with no explanation:

```
$ gem "taskjuggler", "~> 3.2.0"
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
Unknown command taskjuggler,
```

Also, the [installation page](http://www.taskjuggler.org/tj3/manual/Installation.html#Installation) tells nothing about how to run it.

How do I run this program?

**--update:**

```
$PATH 
bash: /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games: No such file or directory
```

Comment: can you add what your $PATH is?

Comment: @jrg added to the question

Comment: Does this work? http://askubuntu.com/questions/30234/installed-ruby-1-9-2-but-new-gems-wont-create-scripts-into-usr-bin

Comment: Not.. the behavior is the same. By the way, which of the 3 commands I'm trying is the correct one to run the app?

Comment: Is this gem meant to be a binary executable or is it meant to be used as `require gemname` in other ruby scripts?

Comment: @nikhil I really don't know. I never used a gem before.

Answer (score 3):

It might sound rude but try reading the [manual](http://www.taskjuggler.org/tj3/manual/index.html) for that gem first.
The usage for the gem is

```
tj3 --version
```

Comment: This command line shows the version, ok, but how do I start it? I see no explicit topic in the manual about starting, the topic "your first project" make it looks like you have to program a software to create a project, but on the screenshot I saw a graphical application, how do I start that graphical application?

Comment: The command line `tj3` alone gives me `Error: You must provide at least one .tjp file`, and an empty `.tjp` file shows `Error: Unexpected token '<END>' found. Expecting one of 'include', 'macro', 'project'`. Can't I start a new empty project?

Comment: can you tell me where you saw your screenshot?

Comment: Try following chap 4 in the manual. It tells you how to create your first project.